# Delete Message from OpenFire server

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to make a control panel for my chat app, the control panel allows the admin to delete undesired messages, but when I delete the message from the ofArchiveMessages, the message keeps appearing to the users.
so where OpenFire delete messages !

Answer (score 0):

Are messages appearing on message history query ? If so then there's somethings wrong. Openfire stores messages in ofArchiveMessages for archiving and general + offline messages are being stored in ofMessage.

Comment: I checked my 'of ' database and I can't find the ofMessage table, about the ofMessageArchive it is store messages for archiving only I can't delete the message from there, when I tried to delete one, it still appearing when I join the room

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmed: We have a similar app where we are deleting messages and which should not be visible to users.

First lets understand a basic standard rule that you should not delete the messages permanenetly form your table. It can be required later on for analytics purpose or any user might claim on something.

So what you can do is, in the ofMessageArchive table add a new Boolean column which flags deleted as true to the messages which will be deleted by your admin.

Then you can simply edit your query to include

> where deleted = false